# DNS Zone - redirect mail to another ip

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm have my DNS server set like this:

```
mail    A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mail    MX  10
```

because I want to redirect all mail traffic on server `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` but it does not forward my emails to this address..

Is there anything else I should do to make it happen?
Any help appriciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have your DNS entries propagated correctly via tools like

```
dig yourdomain.tld MX
```

if you are in unix/linux world

or

```
nslookup
```

tool if you are in windows world

From your question, it seems it might only be the DNS propagation delay.

Is there any mailserver located at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( your MX ip) ?

Comment: It looks good on dig, so it's probably destination mail server fault, thanks for help..

Comment: please repeat after me - _DNS does not have a propagation delay_!

Answer (score 2):

`mx` resource records don't require that the questioner know the answer already.

For an `mx` resource record to work for `mail.example.com.`, the questioner would have to already know that `mail.example.com.` was the target.  Clearly, that's nonsense.

When mail is addressed to `postmaster@example.com`, the domain name looked up is the one in the mailbox name, `example.com.`.  *That* is the domain name which must own the `mx` resource records (if any).  These resource records form the first halves of two-part mappings from the mailbox domain name to sets of IP addresses:

```
example.com. IN MX 10 a.mx.example.com.
example.com. IN MX 20 b.mx.example.com.
a.mx.example.com. IN A 10.25.0.1
a.mx.example.com. IN A 10.25.0.2
b.mx.example.com. IN A 10.25.1.1
```